# Is there a way to use ffmpeg binary on anroid platform in MAUI project?

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg, maui, android-ffmpeg

Currently I'm working on my test project about capabilities of MAUI and ffmpeg, so I can create my own applications. I got stuck on problem about using ffmpeg on platforms other than Windows (for example Anroid).

I tried googling the problem, didn't find anything helpful. Right now my ffmpeg for Android binary is situated inside `Platforms/Android/Assets/libs` as AndroidAsset. And I'm using code below to put my binary on Android to execute in the future

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) != Permission.Granted 
        || ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) != Permission.Granted 
        || ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.Internet) != Permission.Granted) 
    {
        ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] {
          Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage, Manifest.Permission.Internet
        }, 0);
    }

    PrepareFFmpeg();
}

private void PrepareFFmpeg()
{
    var assetManager = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets;
    string path = "libs/ffmpeg";
    string destinationPath = Path.Combine(Android.App.Application.Context.ApplicationInfo.DataDir, "ffmpeg");

    var directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(destinationPath);
    if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
    }

    using (var inputStream = assetManager.Open(path))
    {
        if (File.Exists(destinationPath)) 
        {
            File.Delete(destinationPath);
        }

        using (var outputStream = File.Create(destinationPath))
        {
            inputStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
        }
    }

    Java.Lang.JavaSystem.SetProperty("java.io.tmpdir", destinationPath);
    Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("chmod 700 " + destinationPath);

    FFmpeg.SetExecutablesPath(destinationPath);
}
```

```
public static class FFmpegService
{
    public static async Task ConvertVideoAsync(string inputPath, string outputPath, string format)
    {
        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
        {
            string ffmpegPath = GetFFmpegPath();
            string arguments = $"-i \"{inputPath}\" \"{outputPath}.{format}\"";

            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = ffmpegPath,
                Arguments = arguments,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
            };

            using Process process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
            process.Start();
            await process.WaitForExitAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            //IConversion conversion = await FFmpeg.Conversions.FromSnippet.Convert(inputPath, $"{outputPath}.{f*-  .ormat}");
            //string command = $"-i {inputPath} -f {format} {outputPath}";

            //ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            //psi.FileName = FFmpeg.ExecutablesPath;
            //psi.Arguments = command;
            //psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            //psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
            //psi.UseShellExecute = false;

            //Process process = Process.Start(psi);
            //process.WaitForExit();

            //string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            //string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            string outputPathWithFormat = $"{outputPath}.{format}";
            IConversion conversion = await FFmpeg.Conversions.FromSnippet.Convert(inputPath, outputPathWithFormat);
            IConversionResult result = await conversion.Start();
        }
    }

    private static string GetFFmpegPath()
    {
        //string platformFolder = RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows) ? "Windows" : "Android";
        //return Path.Combine("Platforms", platformFolder, "ffmpeg", "ffmpeg");
        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
        {
            return Path.Combine("Platforms", "Windows", "ffmpeg", "ffmpeg");
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use `FFmpegService` to convert video in any desired format I can by passing it in the arguments of the method (Windows works fine).

In my service I also tried to use `Xabe.FFmpeg` but it always gives `couldn't find part of path (path here)`. When using more manual approach I face another problem every time: `Permission denied`.
For path I tried `/data/data/APPNAME` and cache directories. It always results in problems mentioned above.

I downloaded FFmpeg binary from this repository: https://github.com/tomaszzmuda/Xabe.FFmpeg/releases/tag/executables

My goal is to get conversion working for any format and for at least two platforms: **Android** and **Windows**, but if  you can tell me how to do it on other platforms as well - I would be grateful.

Additional question: If you can tell me the best practice setting standard path for storing converted audio and video, thanks.

If you need more details, please specify I would happily provide them.
P.S.: don't look at the quality of code, I tried to code this for week so I didn't care about quality, I just want to learn how can I do this.

Thanks for your time and attention!

Project: **Maui Blazor .Net 7.0**

Comment: There are numerous posts about using Xamarin and FFmpeg that should largely apply to MAUI also

Comment: Don't know much about Xamarin or MAUI programming for Android, but if you develop a regular app in Android Studio with Java or Kotlin and want to include ffmpeg library, you'll need ffmpeg dynamic libraries specifically compiled for Android platform. Normally there're multiple `.so` files in `lib/<platform>/` forlder of the final package, like `libavcodec.so`, `libavformat.so`, `libavutil.so`.

Comment: It's a manually compiled ffmpeg library (cross-compiled usually) or using a prebuilt library like https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit. Not sure if `Xabe.FFmpeg` is suitable for Android, maybe it's Windows only solution.

Comment: On the other hand, check you permissions in the manifest. Again, not sure about .NET side, but in classic Android dev environment I have `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. And I launch an intent to ask for "Manage all files permission" when starting the app. Basically, check this guide https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files.

Comment: Then you can basically use any path from your internal storage. In my case I specified the full path for testing, like `/storage/emulated/0/<my-created-folder>` which points to a custom folder in the internal storage root.